# Changing direction of jquery width/height animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I've just started learning how to animate using jQuery and I am having trouble finding a solution (if there even is one) to a small aesthetic issue I am having.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cause_button").css("cursor","pointer");
$(".cause_button").on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height:100, width:100, opacity:1.0}, "fast");
});
$(".cause_button").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height:75, width:75, opacity:.75}, "fast");s
});
});
</script>
```

It's a pretty simple hover in/out animation on an image with a class of ".cause_button". The animation works well but expands the width/height down and to the right. Is there any way that I could get the image to expand outward in all directions?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FHkw2/1/

PS: I understand that there are CSS3 alternatives using the transition effects but they achieve the same result and seem less compatible with browsers so I am trying to focus on using jQuery for this.

Comment: could you set up a jsfiddle to illustrate that problem?

Comment: Absolutely, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/FHkw2/1/

I replaced my button images with some basic circle img from google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "top" and "left" attributes during aniomation:

```
$(".cause_button").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:100, width:100, opacity:1.0, left: -13, top: -13}, "fast");
});
$(".cause_button").on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({height:75, width:75, opacity:.75, left: 0, top: 0}, "fast");
});
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FjNy5/2/

And i recommend you to use on() like documentation let it do:

```
$(".cause_button").on({
    'mouseenter': function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:100, width:100, opacity:1.0, left: -13, top: -13}, "fast");
    }, 
    'mouseleave': function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:75, width:75, opacity:.75, left: 0, top: 0}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ETu3A/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cause_button").css("cursor","pointer");
  $(".cause_button").css("position","relative"); // required for offset positioning
  $(".cause_button").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
      left: -12.5, top: -12.5,
      height:100, width:100, opacity:1.0}, "fast");
  });
  $(".cause_button").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
      left: 0, top: 0,
      height:75, width:75, opacity:.75}, "fast");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have a better result if you set your button to `display:absolute` and wrap it in a container element that uses `display:relative`. Then, adjust the css left and right properties of your button element during the animation. In situations like this I prefer to set some initial styles on elements for their "starting position" then put css that doesn't change in to a css file.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htasM/) to demo this idea and help illustrate those points.