# jQuery - grow div from center to animate in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Alright I have these divs that I have been animating in/out previously by doing `hide()` or `show()`, however that does not look clean and Id like to have them grow out from the center, i.e. grow from width of nothing to their current width.

I am new to jquery animations and don't know how to do this properly. I have tried setting the initial width to 0 and doing:

```
function panelIn(labDiv) {
  var neww = "700px";
  $(labDiv).animate({
    width: neww
  }, 2000);
}
```

But that grows the div to the right. How can I achieve this? Are there any good ;libraries for animating in divs, i.e. introducing them on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing direction of jquery width/height animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559310/changing-direction-of-jquery-width-height-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to just use CSS and `.toggleClass()`.

## CSS

```
#labDiv{
   height:700px;
   width:700px;
   transform:scale(0);
   transform-origin:center center;
   transition: transform 2000ms ease;
}

#labDiv.show{
   transform:scale(1);
}
```

## jQuery

```
function panelIn(labDiv){
    labDiv.toggleClass('show');
}
```